# How to write this in a generic way (state machine that uses a counter that can increment per project )

Tags: vhdl

I am trying to write this code in a generic way. Is there a way to replace numbers with generic expressions. (1,2,3..max) "max" will change per project and during the project. Every time there is a new variable, I add one more line to the end of code change the number by myself.

I tried writing max, max -1, max-2 max-3 .. But this is not OK when max is a generic.

```vhdl
 case state_counter is
                when max-6 => block_output  <= variable_a;
                when max-5 => block_output  <= variable_b
                when max-4 => block_output  <= variable_c;
                when max-3 => block_output  <= variable_d;
                .....
                when max-1  => block_output  <= something;
                when max    => block_output  <= something_else;
```

```vhdl
 case state_counter is
                when 1 => block_output  <= variable_a;
                when 2 => block_output  <= variable_b
                when 3 => block_output  <= variable_c;
                when 4 => block_output  <= variable_d;
                .....
                when max-1  => block_output  <= something;
                when max    => block_output  <= something_else;
```

Answer (score 0):

A bit of a work around, but can you put all your variables into an array and then just choose the variable from that array? You will have to place the variables into the array. I haven't tried to compile it, but it should look something like this.

Assuming the output is a slv(7 downto 0) and you have genereic MAX to set the size

```
architecture A1 of example is
 type t_output_array is array (INTEGER range <>) of std_logic_vector(7 downto 0);
 signal output_array : t_output_array(1 to MAX);
 signal I : integer range 0 to MAX; -- To select in the array
begin
 process( CLK )
  begin
   if Rising_edge( CLK ) then
      block_output  <= output_array(I);
    end if;
  end process;
end architecture A1;
```

An alternative would be to somehow use a generate statement. You could try to play around with it to see if you can create a process that the numbers and list from a set range.

```
G1: for I in 0 to N generate
  -- Component instances and/or process
end generate G1;
```